# FOR BEGINNERS, what is HIGHLY recommended ? storing image(profile picture, at least 1MB?) to database or through filesystem?

Tags: database, pdo, xampp, filesystems

if each user is storing a profile-picture size image (max 9 pictures per user) what is better to use store it ? I can't find related to my question and I can't comment yet.

Comment: This question is opinion-based. Also, you should give more detail about the use case.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most recommended way of storing images is to store the path to the images in your database instead of the image itself.

It makes your database size very lightweight and also this way you can easily use your path anywhere you want, like in `src` attribute of `img` tag